# Format of site url in facebook app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

what is the format of the site url of the facebook app.Is it something like:-

```
http://www.mysite.com/
or
http://www.mysite.com
or
http://mysite.com/
or
http://mysite.com
or
with index.php like:-
http://www.mysite.com/index.php
or
http://mysite.com/index.php and so on as above or without "http".
```

can anyone suggest please, what is the right format?
Thanks

Comment: also look at [this](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/4691782/facebook-api-error-191/4691841#4691841)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's entirely up to you. If the non www version of your site redirects to the www. version put the www. How is your domain set-up? Does it use both or just one?

e.g can I access www.mysite.com and mysite.com and they both show the same thing?

Just make sure you are consistent, and you choose one format. It doesn't matter to facebook which one you choose. However you do need the trailing slash in the app settings or a ? after index.php if you use that

Comment: And what about '/' ? Is it necessary ?

Comment: You mean that both 1st and 3rd formats in the question would work.right?

Comment: Yes they should do. And if it ends in a file (like index.php) you need to put a question mark at the end as if it's starting a query string. It does normally prompt you for this when creating an app